# In Excel; Can LOOKUP return more than one cell as a result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Lookup has two different usage:

```
Lookup( value, array )
```

and

```
Lookup( value, lookup_range, result_range )
```

I want to return more than one cell when it found the value.
Like:

```
=LOOKUP(A17;'Products'!A:A;'Products'!C:D)
```

C column has its price, D Colum has its currency. And i want to multiply price with local currency to show everything in one currency.

How can i take the results one by one ?

```
A          B            C           D
Product1   xxxx         10          €
Product2   xxxx         5           $
```

C and D will return but how can i access them?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want it returned.  If you want it returned as a concatenated field you can do something like this:

```
=LOOKUP(A17;'Products'!A:A;'Products'!C:C)&LOOKUP(A17;'Products'!A:A;'Products'!D:D)
```

Or if you want to return it into two different cells you could use the two formulas seperately:

```
=LOOKUP(A17;'Products'!A:A;'Products'!C:C)
=LOOKUP(A17;'Products'!A:A;'Products'!D:D)
```

**Edit:**  If you tell us a little more about where and how you are storing your exchange rates, we could use those to turn everything into US Dollars also using a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
=LOOKUP(A17;'Products'!A:A;'Products'!C:C) * LOOKUP(A17;'Products'!A:A;'Products'!D:D)
```

Comment: according to the question, it seems that column D is not the exchange rate